# Magento2 InstallData.php Does't working on registration page

Tags: customer-account, magento-2.1.3

i need to add new field in magento2 registration form so i was created new module **Kratos/Seller**.

It's working the custom attribute created on database but if i submit customer registration form it show error massage " We Can't save the customer".

I hope the problem is **setup/InstallData.php** file if remove the file customer will be saved successfully but data will not stored in database.

setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
  namespace Kratos\Sellers\Setup;
  use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
/**
 * Customer setup factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;
/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
{
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}
/**
 * Installs DB schema for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "seller_shop_name",  array(
        "type"     => "varchar",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "seller_shop_name",
        "input"    => "text",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "unique"     => true,
        "is_used_in_grid" => true,
        "is_visible_in_grid" => true,
        "is_filterable_in_grid" => true,
        "is_searchable_in_grid" => true
    ));

    $seller_shop_name = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "seller_shop_name");

    $seller_shop_name = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'seller_shop_name');
    //$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    //$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    //$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $seller_shop_name->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $seller_shop_name->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

what is problem of my code why it's show this error msg when i submitting form

Comment: please let me know if you have issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below two files in your custom module,

**app/code/Package/Customerattribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="extra_attributes" template="Package_Customerattribute::customer-attribute.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Package/Customerattribute/view/frontend/templates/customer-attribute.phtml**

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="seller_shop_name" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('seller shop name') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="seller_shop_name" id="seller_shop_name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('seller shop name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" autocomplete="off" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Clear Cache and check.

Comment: These two files i already having but till now showing error when i submitting form

Comment: which error showing?

Comment: We can't save the customer.

Comment: This error will be showing form value will be added customer_entity table but customer account page did't open

Comment: customer login page user mail-id and password validation based on customer_grid_flag table when i submit form data did't save customer_grid_flag